# How to add multiline string to a text file in java?

Tags: java, string, base64, line, filewriter

This is where i am forming a multiline string that should be written to a file..

```
   Base64 encoder = new Base64(64,System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
    String cert_begin = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"+ System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String end_cert =  System.getProperty("line.separator")+"-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

    byte[] derCert = cert.getEncoded();

    String pemCertPre = new String(encoder.encode(derCert));

    String pemCert = cert_begin + pemCertPre + end_cert;
    return pemCert;
```

Below shows the code used to write the file..

```
        String PEMString = convertToPem(cert);

        FileWriter PEMWriter = new FileWriter(PEMFile, false);
        PEMWriter.write(PEMString);

        //flush the file
        PEMWriter.flush();
```

When i was writing to the file, pemCertPre alone is being written in a single line..

And Base64 is imported 
from

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64
```

Comment: Hmm. That `64` parameter is supposed to be the line width. Are you sure the system property works correctly? Why not hardcode to `'\n'`?

Comment: System.getProperty works correctly.. i am getting the string in multiline.. but the problem is, i couldn't write multiline string to the file

Comment: Does your `PEMString` contain line ends?

Comment: yea.. PEMString contains the line ends..

Answer (score 0):

Hey I use BufferedWriter when I write to files. Maybe you could try that instead. I have written a basic writer in the main method as an example and the other two methods are for the problem you have. However there is an error in the first method covertToPem() I take it that cert is type "Certificate"

Hope this helps.

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    File file = new File("subfolder/path/fileName.txt");
    String a = "one";
    String b = "two";
    char ch = 't';
    try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

        writer.write(a);
        writer.newLine(); //makes new line

        writer.write(b);
        writer.newLine();

        writer.write(ch);
        writer.newLine();

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    //try is instead

    private String[] convertToPem(Certificate cert){
        String[] pemCert = new String[3];

        try{
          Base64 encoder = new Base64(64,System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
            String cert_begin = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"+ System.getProperty("line.separator");
            String end_cert =  System.getProperty("line.separator")+"-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

            byte[] derCert = cert.getEncoded();

            String pemCertPre = new String(encoder.encode(derCert));

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pemCert;
    }

    private void writeToFile(File fileLoaction){

        Certificate cert = null;
        String[] pemCert = convertToPem(cert);

        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileLoaction));

            for(int i=0; i<pemCert.length; i++){
                writer.write(pemCert[i]);
                writer.newLine();
            }

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

the imports

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64;
```